# В чем разница между extend и append?

Tags: python

Я немного не понимаю в чем разница между append и extend в структурах данных, на конкретной ситуации.

```
a = [1]
a.append(a)
print(a)
#[1, [...]]
```

но

```
a = [1]
a.extend(a)
print(a)
#[1, 1]
```

но

```
a = 1,
a += a
print(a)
#(1, 1)
```

Как я понимаю в первом случае я создаю список, в него засовываю его же, но так как он уже изменился, и айди осталось то же, то ему придется себя еще раз изменить рекурсивно и так далее.
В третьем мы изменяем кортеж, но изменяем его айди и соответсвенно, тот кортеж уже не тот, что после.
Но что во втором не так?

Comment: Подтверждаю, абсолютно тождественный результат. Вопрос -  откуда ТС взял результат первого примера??? Вернее так: результат предъявленный ТС может получиться в случае использования конструкции a.extend([a])

Comment: В первом случае список содержит *ссылку* на себя самого в качестве одного из элементов. Еще раз для этого ничего менять не придется. Разницы между этим списком и списком, содержащим ссылку на *другой* список, практически нет. А вот при выводе такого списка можно уйти в бесконечную рекурсию. Чтобы этого избежать, библиотечная функция просто выводит троеточие.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**a.append(x)** тупо берет элемент **x** как есть и добавляет его в список **a**. **x** может быть что угодно, оно просто добавится в список. Если **x** список, то в **a** добавится **один элемент** - список **x**. А в **extend** нужно передавать **итератор**, который **поэлементно** добавится в список.

Answer (score 5):

```
a.extend(a)
```

Это полностью эквивалентно коду:

```
for x in a.copy():
    a.append(x)
```

И при этом совершенно не важно, что находится в `a`, главное чтобы по этому можно было проитерироваться, ну и чтобы `a.append` работало.

**Update**: Поставил `a.copy()`, extrn прав, вот не проверишь код - и окажется какая-нибудь засада.

Comment: `a.extend(a)` это скорее `for x in list(a): a.append(x)`, потому, что что цикл в вашем примере будет бесконечным (пока не съест всю память) из за того, что `a` пополняется в процессе итерации по нему.

Answer (score 4):

- `.append()` принимает как аргумент **1 элемент**, который добавится к списку,
- `.extend()` принимает как аргумент **список**, которого **все элементы** добавятся к списку.

Comment: Не только список, любой итератор

Comment: @CrazyElf, конечно, вы прав, но я сознательно дал такой краткий ответ, чтобы объяснить только суть разницы и притом не испугать и не отвлекать внимание. :-)

Answer (score 1):

append добавляет объект, extend расширяет, то есть extend аналогичен append за исключением того что параметром может служить лишь итерируемый объект, который распаковывается

```
x=[1]
x.append([2])
#[1,[2]]
x.extend([3])
#[1,[2],3]
xx=[4,5]
x.extend(xx)
#[1,[2],3,4,5]
x.append(xx)
#[1,[2],3,4,5,[4,5]]
x.extend(*[xx])
#[1,[2],3,4,5,[4,5],4,5]
[].extend(*[xx])==[].append(xx) #unpack then append
#True
```